# Change active background color of each tab in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to have different active background colors for diffrent tabs?

Here is my code:

```
import { TabNavigator, TabBarTop } from 'react-navigation'
import React from 'react'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome';
import Home from '../home/Home.js'
import About from '../home/About.js'

var Routes = TabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => (<Icon name='music' size={20} color={'white'}/>)
        }
    },
    About: {
        screen: About,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => (<Icon name='search' size={20} color={'white'}/>)
        }
    }
},{
    tabBarComponent: TabBarTop,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: false,
        tabStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#614971'
        }
    }
});

export default Routes;
```

Which gives this:

[image]

And this is what i want:
https://uimovement.com/media/resource_image/Tapbar.gif

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It doesn't look like you can with the package's props that are open to you. I only see that you can set an active background color for all tabs [Tab Nav Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html) Maybe you can monkey patch it based off the route ‍♂️

Comment: Okay thank you for the response!

Comment: No problem @Shivansh Nalwaya